# How to expand/collapse Flutter listview and gridview from specific index or row using ExpansionPanel?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I want to make my listview/gridview expandable with user's onTap action - let say I have a gridview like below

```
  return GridView.builder(
      gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
        crossAxisCount: 5,
        crossAxisSpacing: 2,
        mainAxisSpacing: 2,
        childAspectRatio: 1.825,
      ),
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0),
      physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
      shrinkWrap: true,
      itemCount: buttons.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return buttons[index]; // length is 25 so we have 5 rows
      },
    );
  }
```

In this case, I want to set initial visible grid row with 3 then when user tap some icon below of this gridview (like down arrow), it will expand to show everything (5 rows since we have 25 items inside `buttons`. ).

In another scenario when I use `ListView` and has `itemCount: 10` for example, I want to limit visible list item with 5 for initial view and expandable to show all 10 items by placing the down arrow like below.
[image]

Flutter team provides the widget `ExpansionPanel`, however, this simply expand/collapse entire widget not from specific index or row.
I want to know if there is any way I can implement this kind of logic - if you can provide some simple code example it would be very helpful.

[image]

Comment: Maybe I should wrap ListView with container and Expansion Panel?

Answer (score 0):

Please return this widget in ListView/GridView itemBuilder.

```
Theme(
data: Theme.of(context!).copyWith(
    dividerColor: Colors.transparent, canvasColor: Colors.transparent),
child: ListTileTheme(
    dense: true,
    minVerticalPadding: 0.0,
    child: Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
        color: Colors.white,
      ),
      child: ExpansionTile(
        initiallyExpanded: false,
        tilePadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 0, horizontal: 8),
        childrenPadding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        title: Text("your text"),
        children: [],
      ),
    )
),
)
```